# What is the equation of a line with these properties?

Tags: trigonometry

It is a tangent graph. with vertical asymptote at $\pi/2$ and the period is $\pi/4$

My first thought is that it is $\tan(4x-\pi/2)$

Is this wrong? THe points $(9\pi/16, 5)$ and $(11\pi/16, 1)$ are on the tangent line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good work with the $4x$ part.

Then, if you were to plug in $\displaystyle x=\frac{\pi}{2}$, you would have $\displaystyle \tan\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)$, which, indeed, does not exist.

So, you answer is correct!

Also note, any tangent graph of the form $\displaystyle a\tan(4x-\frac{\pi}{2})+b$ would also work.